# Not allowing reply to a mail in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

As of CodeIgniter's `$this->email->reply_to('you@example.com', 'Your Name')` function sets the reply-to address. If the information is not provided the information in the "from" function is used.

I don't want the users to reply me back. What should be done to prevent user's reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent someone from pushing the "Reply" button in a mail client. However you can use a different "from" address when sending your emails (`noreply@example.com`) : An email box that does not exists or that exists but always emptied automatically without someone really looking at it.